# Creating generic Objective C relationship model

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data

I'm trying to setup generic model for retrieving data from a backend and processing the data in my iPhone app. I'm trying to accomplish this by creating a base-class for all class in which all logic is defined for retrieving, saving and linking data. This last part is the part I'm struggling on.

In every class I define the object name (in Core Data) and if a certain object has relationships to other objects, also and array of the names of the objects with two arrays (one for hasOne and one for hasMany).

However I can't seem to accomplish cast retrieved objects to a certain class which is stored as a string. This is the code I currently have:

```
/**
 Update the relationsships of an object which has relationsships from the type 'HasOne'.

 @param object
    Object from which the relations has to be updated.
 */
- (void)updateRelationshipsHasOne:(id)object {

    for(NSString *relation in self.hasOne) {        
        Class class = NSClassFromString(self.table);
        id anInstance = [class alloc];
        anInstance = object;        

        NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@_id",[relation lowercaseString]];

        id delegata = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegata managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:relation inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"db_id == %i",[[object valueForKey:key] intValue]];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        if(fetchedObjects && [fetchedObjects count] > 0) {
            id otherInstance = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

            SEL s = NSSelectorFromString([[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"set%@",relation]);
            [anInstance performSelector:s withObject:otherInstance];
        }

    }

}
```

If I cast both 'anInstance' and 'otherInstance' to the desired classes, everything goes well. However the whole purpose is to make the method generic, so I need some way to be able to cast both variables to Classes which are stored as strings.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Edit:
The error message I'm receiving is:

```
2016-03-21 20:34:19.024 DeDamen[12303:834645] -[Heat setEvent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe2829d8cd0
2016-03-21 20:34:19.026 DeDamen[12303:834645] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Heat setEvent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe2829d8cd0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109e68e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001094c0deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109e7148d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109dbe90a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109dbe4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   *******                             0x0000000105d255ab -[CommonBase updateRelationshipsHasOne:] + 1627
    6   *******                             0x0000000105d24e60 -[CommonBase updateRelationships:] + 256
    7   *******                             0x0000000105d248a9 -[CommonBase save:handler:] + 1065
****
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

In here the model 'Heat' refers to the object 'anInstance' and the model 'Event' refers to the object 'otherInstance'. The relations ship is: a Heat has one Event and an Event has many Heats'

Comment: why do you need to cast them?  does using 'id' not work?

Comment: Do the last two statements `NSSelectorFromString` and `performSelector` do the same as `setValue:forKey:`? You might be overcomplicating things.

Comment: If I'm correct you do neet to cast them. Thing is that if you have model1 and model2, then model1 has a method setModel2 and model2 has a method addModel1 (in a hasMany relationship).

Comment: What happens if you don't cast them?

Comment: I included the error messages as a reference

Comment: change set%@ with set%@: , it will create method setEvent: (with parameter) instead of setEvent ( without parameter )

Comment: I cannot vote for answers, but @ogres you saved my day! The double dot was the cause of all this!